# Recovery partition at the middle of disk

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, system-reserved-partition

I own a Samsung laptop, which came with Windows 8 preinstalled, it was updated to Windows 10. Then I installed Ubuntu, to do it I created 4 partitions, swap, boot, root, and home.
But linux ran out of space, so I shrank the C: unit in order to resize linux partitions. But I have my partitions in this order:

- sda1 NTFS (Windows Recovery) 500 MiB
- sda2 FAT32 (EFI system) 300 MiB
- sda3 (MSR) 128 MiB
- **sda4 NTFS (Windows C:) 250 GiB**
- **151.68 GiB Free**
- sda10 (linux swap) 4.88 GiB
- **sda5 NTFS (Recovery) 813 MiB**
- sda9 ext4 (/boot) 977 MiB
- sda11 ext4 (/) 9.54 GiB
- sda12 ext4 (/home) 24.51 GiB
- sda6 NTFS (Recovery) 350 MiB
- sda7 NTFS (Samsung-REC2) 21.16 GiB
- sda8 FAT32 (Samsung_REC) 1 GiB

So I realized I cant resize my linux partitions without moving the recovery partition, however, I'm afraid the partition won't be recognized or won't be useful if i move it, i plan to move it towards the bottom of the disk, behind /home partition, but linux partitions will also be moved.
What should i do?

EDIT: A gparted [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33S05.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know whether it is safe to move the recovery partition or not, so I understand your concern. If I had to guess I would say it is possible, but don't quote me.

In case you don't get more useful answer, you may consider this scenario:

1. Boot some live CD Linux.
2. Create a new partition in free space. The plan is: this will be your new `/home`. Create filesystem. Mount under `/mnt/target`.
3. Mount `sda12` as `/mnt/source`; mount `sda11` as `/mnt/ubuntu`.
4. Copy the data from `source` to `target` with `sudo cp -a`. Be careful not to get `/mnt/target/source/` structure. It is uncommon to have hidden directories or files directly under `/home/`, nevertheless check if you have them.
5. Adjust `/mnt/ubuntu/etc/fstab` (save a copy just in case!) to use your new partition instead the old one as Ubuntu `/home`.
6. Check if all your data from `source` is in `target`.
7. Check again.
8. You may boot your Ubuntu to verify if it starts with the new `/home`. Again -- check if all your data is there. Go back to live CD then.
9. Destroy `sda12`.
10. Expand `sda11`.

This way you will get about 150 GB for `/home` and about 34 GB for `/`.

Additional hints:

- If you want to expand swap (`sda10`), do it beforehand.
- The scenario requires some knowledge about `/etc/fstab`. You may find the `blkid` command useful while editing the `fstab`.